# Hide Rows and Columns That Are Empty

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

On Open, In Worksheet "Time per Job & Job Costing", if Row from column A is empty or includes a 0 value hide it. If Column from row 1 is empty or includes a `0` value hide it.

I looked around and can find techniques for hiding rows if a column is empty but not the other way around, nor if the value is `0`.

I have the Rows accomplished with this, but it only works on empty rows:

```
function onOpen(e) {

["Time per Job & Job Costing"].forEach(function (s) {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
        .getSheetByName(s)
    sheet.getRange('A:A')
        .getValues()
        .forEach(function (r, i) {
            if (!r[0]) sheet.hideRows(i + 1)
        });
    });
  

}
```

Comment: Can you provide some code to show what you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If Column from row 1 is empty or includes a 0 value hide it.

### Explanation:

- I believe your goal is to **hide** a column if a cell of that column
  in the **first** row is **empty** or **0**. You also want to achieve that when you open the spreadsheet file.
- To achieve that, the first step is to get the values of the first row. You can use [getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) to get the first row starting from the first column until the last column with content. For the latter you need to use [getLastColumn()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastcolumn). Then you can [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)ten the array in order to perform a [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop. For every element in the first row, you check whether it is empty or 0. If this condition evaluates to `true` then you [hide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hidecolumnscolumnindex) that particular column.

---

### Solution:

```
function onOpen() {
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Time per Job & Job Costing');
  const first_row = sh.getRange(1,1,1,sh.getMaxColumns()).getValues().flat();
  
  first_row.forEach((fr,i)=>{
  if(fr=='' || fr==0){
  sh.hideColumns(i+1);
  }});
  
}
```

Comment: Your solution works except for the last two columns in the spreadsheet, which are empty. When I combine what I already have used for the rows with your code I am 99% of the way there.

Comment: @user2748807 thanks for your feedback. If you want to apply this logic to **every** column in your sheet, then please try my updated solution. I replaced `getLastColumn` with `getMaxColumns`.